# Make subfolder the root folder for everything in subfolder

Tags: .htaccess

I am working on a project that i host on my server.

My server is mydomain.com and i want my project to run in mydomain.com/project.

I wish to put an htaccess file in the project subfolder, so that in every file of the project, / will point to mydomain.com/project instead of mydomain.com

So / will be mydomain/project,
/lib/img will be mydomain/project/lib/img,
etc.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you may change your DocumentRoot (apache) value:
add "/project" at the end